# I'm not able to use my own svg icon with Vuetify 3 preprend-icon

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm using the latest version of vuetify with Nuxt 3. I have tried several solutions as registering the icon as a separate vue component but it doesn't work.

```
<v-list-item prepend-icon="mdi-account-multiple" title="Shared with me" value="shared"></v-list-item>
```

What is the easiest way to pass my own SVG to prepend-icon ?

What I've tried:

1. Created myIcon.vue

```
    <template>
        <div>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" width="30" height="30"><path fill="#ff0000" d="xxx" /></svg>
            
        </div>
    </template>
    
    <script setup lang="ts">
    defineProps({
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            default: "",
        },
    });
    </script>
```

2. Created myIconRender.ts

```
    import { h } from "vue";
    import type { IconSet, IconProps } from "vuetify";
    import myIcon from "@/components/common/myIcon.vue";
    
    const Icon: IconSet = {
      component: (props: IconProps) => {
        return h(myIcon, {
          name: props.icon as string
        });
      },
    };
    
    export { myIcon };
```

3. Imported myIconRender.ts in vuetify.js and added to createVutify my IconSet:

```
    import { myIcon } from '~/components/common/myIconRender';
    export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
      const vuetify = createVuetify({
        theme: {
          defaultTheme: 'light',
          themes: {
            myCustomLightTheme,
          },
        },
        ssr: true,
        components,
        directives,
        icons: {
          defaultSet: 'mdi',
          sets: {
            custom: myIcon,
          },
        },
      });
    
      nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify);
    });
```